# How to create a BitmapImage from std::string of png data in UWP using C++/CX

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

I want to create a BitmapImage from std::string of png data in C++/CX. Here is my code. BitmapImage is being created but when binded with the Image elements source in Xaml it is not getting displayed.

```
void setImage(std::string imageDataStr, uint64_t len) {

    auto stream = ref new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    auto writer = ref new DataWriter(stream->GetOutputStreamAt(0));

    Platform::Array<unsigned char>^ data = ref new Platform::Array<unsigned char>((unsigned char*)imageDataStr.data(), len);
    writer->WriteBytes(data);

    create_task(writer->StoreAsync()).then([=](unsigned bytesStored)
    {
        Image->SetSource(stream);
    });
}
```

Am i doing anything wrong??

Any suggestions?

Comment: stream->Seek(0); needs to be added to ensure it starts reading the bitmap data from the start of the stream.  Do avoid storing binary data in a string.

Comment: stream->Seek(0); also does not work. It is better to not keep binary data in a string, but from the internal API i use for network request i get only data as string.

Comment: So instead of fixing your networking abstraction you move on, and break another interface. Not wise.